# CMake OSX build finds different SDK with makefiles generator and Xcode generator

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, cmake

I am working on a cross platform project that uses cmake.

On Mac OS, most of my colleagues use Xcode, but I prefer Clion (which uses the makefile generator). After a recent commit, I started getting build errors:

```
<name>.h:26:8: error: unknown type name 'NSErrorDomain'
```

Those errors aren't there in the Xcode version of the project. Upon further investigation, it appears that the Unix Makefiles generated project used by Clion is pulling in a different version of the SDK and of NSError.h. The version included in the makefile project does not include a definition of NSErrorDomain.

With the following snippet added to my main CMakelists.txt :

```
find_library(AUDIO_UNIT AudioUnit)
message ( STATUS "AUDIO_UNIT = ${AUDIO_UNIT}" )

find_path ( NSERROR "NSError.h" )
message ( STATUS "NSERROR = ${NSERROR}")
```

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../

```
-- AUDIO_UNIT = /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework
-- NSERROR = /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers
```

cmake -G "Xcode" ../

```
-- AUDIO_UNIT = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework
-- NSERROR = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers
```

So the Xcode generator project seems to know to use the SDK in the Xcode App bundle, but makefiles is just pulling from /System/Library.

I have tried setting CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT and CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET, but they seem to have no effect.

Is there a way that I can tell the makefile generator to pull from the Xcode App bundle?

Comment: According to documentation, variable [CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT.html) should help. Do you pass it to `cmake` call with `-D` option? Have you cleared the CMake cache after changes? Also, you may try to set *SDKROOT*  environment variable: CMake variable `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` is initialized with its value by default.

Comment: I tried setting CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT, but at the top of the CMakelists.txt, before the first project() command. I did not try setting it from the command line or via the SDKROOT env variable. I suppose it's worth a try. And yes I have tried it with a clean build folder.

Comment: The frameworks are probably the same. OS X fools around with a lot of hard links. Does your source code have all the necessary headers included? XCode may be pulling in some behind the scenes on you. Another option is to change your CLion settings so CMake uses the XCode generator, and `xcodebuild`.

Comment: I have verified that they are not the same. The NSError.h files in those two locations have different contents. I have also verified that the type name NSErrorDomain is new in the version of the sdk that is being pulled in by Xcode and that version is newer than my OS version. Clion will not work with the Xcode generator.